# How to disable ui.bootstrap.pagination

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, pagination, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using [ui.bootstrap.pagination](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/ui.bootstrap.pagination)

I have a search box in a form on my page.
I would like to disable the pagination control while someone is interacting with the search box, then re-enable once they have pressed "Search"

I would like to use the AngularJS form validation

```
ng-valid
ng-invalid
ng-pristine
ng-dirty
```

How would I tie the form validation with disabling the pagination?

I could not find out how to make the pagination control appear as disabled and disable input.  I'm also using Bootstrap 3.

TIA

Comment: I am amazed no one has actually answered this yet..

Comment: I am amazed too. I need to disable the pagination buttons while the ajax hasn't returned yet

Answer (score 2):

The support for directive ngDisabled was added to pagination directive, just an hour ago... ;)

You should be able to block the whole pagination element from outside. Lets say You have variable named blocked in Your scope that indicates when pagination should be blocked. You can then block it like this:

```
<pagination 
    total-items="totalItems" 
    ng-model="currentPage" 
    ng-change="pageChanged()" 
    ng-disabled="blocked"
></pagination>
```

Currently to use it, You shoud build newest version from [official repo](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap) yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I am completely approximating here..

```
<pagination direction-links="false" boundary-links="true" total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage"></pagination>
```

If you have something like that in your page, then you can change it to something like this, assuming your search form is called 'searchForm':

```
<pagination 
     ng-class="{true:'', false:'disable'}[(searchForm.$valid)]"
     direction-links="false" boundary-links="true" 
     total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage"></pagination>
```

where disable is some CSS class that tweaks the pagination controls to make them look disabled.

OR:

```
 <pagination 
     ng-if="!searchForm.$valid"
     direction-links="false" boundary-links="true" 
     total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage"></pagination>
```

Use ng-if or ng-show/hide to toggle visibility of the controls if the form isn't valid.

Comment: The question is how to disable pagination. Not style it like it is disabled, or to hide it completly.

Comment: true. but there was no other answer, so I started somewhere. :-P (as I said, I was approximating). I quite like your answer.